# Openlayers: GML label polyline at x-y location from attribute

Tags: openlayers, qgis

I have a GML file of polylines generated in QGIS which I am displaying in an OpenLayers map. In QGIS the position and rotation of a label on a polyline can be neatly controlled by assigning attributes x, y, and r (lat long and rotation angle) to each polyline. My Question - Is it possible to replicate this in OpenLayers? Currently the code below will display the polylines, assign a line colour (from an attribute) and label the end of a line, but I cannot work out a way of using the x,y,r attributes to position and rotate a label, either with available label styling classes in the current layer, or by creating a new map layer with the labels on hidden points. Alternatively, are there any other methods of labelling polylines, for example dynamic labels (always visible where ever you pan)?

The format of my GML File records is:

```
    <gml:featureMember>
  <ogr:kkt fid="kkt.1">
    <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates>44.812559373349139,35.123067298944513 44.877309206574807,35.090369282888879 44.950560220859877,35.055758183443189 45.018309159587957,35.032504238642005 45.096824639867442,35.010683901054648 45.21229522673363,34.979672029569649 45.279922241108068,34.961918618632232 45.328207131827412,34.944608836480917 45.379400253358313,34.921389158285983 45.438599638041431,34.88848896036766 45.505644158404003,34.837566477843978 45.554152957603797,34.794071273427527 45.595241006031721,34.763023849471629 45.631673146434373,34.739161723332415 45.67708,34.71297</gml:coordinates></gml:LineString></ogr:geometryProperty>
    <ogr:id>2</ogr:id>
    <ogr:thickness>200</ogr:thickness>
    <ogr:col>#00248F</ogr:col>
    <ogr:x>43.4678</ogr:x>
    <ogr:y>35.8826</ogr:y>
    <ogr:r>324</ogr:r>
  </ogr:kkt>
</gml:featureMember>
```

(where the attributes: "thickness" is the text label for the polyline; "col" is the colour assigned to the polyline, x,y,r are the co-ords and rotation attributes for the label)

The Openlayers code I'm using to display the layer is:

```
        var contour = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Contour Lines", {
      strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "kml/temp.gml",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML({
          extractStyles: true,
          extractAttributes: true,
          maxDepth: 2
        })
      }),
      styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
          fillColor: "${col}",
          fillOpacity: 0,
          strokeColor: "${col}",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          fontColor: "black",
          fontFamily: "arial, sans-serif",
          fontSize: ".9em",
          fontWeight: "bold",
          label: "${thickness}",
          labelAlign: "cm",
          labelXOffset: -10
        })
      })
    });
```